# Setting which user flow is "live" on Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I created a user flow for password reset and also for unified sign up/sign in with custom urls. When I go to my site it is still showing the default Azure pages for login/signup/resetpwd. Is there something I am missing to make these user flows "live"? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change the client configuration to point to the new policy in the Authority property - that way your client knows to redirect to the new policy.

**Example**: https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{your-sign-in-sign-up-policy}

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular-spa

Answer (score 1):

In the same way as you did, it was ability to change the page style, but I used the default format  `https://<my b2c name>.b2clogin.com/static/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml` for creating ***sign up and sign in user flow***.
By the way,if you don't click the save button, it does not work.

And if you use [customize the UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview).The following two points need to be noted.

> 1.The important point is that you host the content on a publicly
> available HTTPS endpoint with CORS enabled. You must use an absolute
> URL when you specify it in your content.
>
> 2.Host your content on an HTTPS endpoint (with CORS allowed). Both GET
> and OPTIONS request methods must be enabled when configuring CORS.